# creating netbeans plugin at statusbar

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-plugins

I followed that tutorial to create a simple plugin on netbeans
    https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-google.htmt

That code puts the component at toolbar:

```
public final class SomeAction extends AbstractAction implements Presenter.Toolbar {...}
```

I want to put this plugin at netbeans statusbar (redbox at image), is it possible?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the position attribute

- https://jnkjava.wordpress.com/2011/02/12/recipe-2-status-bar/

And more

- http://www.pellissier.co.za/hermien/?p=295
- https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/superseding_netbeans_platform_status_line
- http://blog.emilianbold.ro/2006/08/netbeans-platform-statuslineelementpro.html

Comment: Using StatusLineElementProvider worked here, thank you.

I found this repository last week, that uses a statusbar too
https://github.com/markiewb/nb-git-branch-in-statusbar